# Regexp expression /(\@)(.*?)(\;)/ failing at quotations

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a helper method that goes through any given block of text and replaces substrings that are in the format '@something;' with a link. It works with all test cases I've tried, including

```
@user; @user name; @user.name; @@user.name; @user*name;
```

but gets hung up on quotations, as in

```
@I'll fight you;
```

but still matches up until that point? Below, for hacky debugging purposes, I have the helper method putting three asterisks ('*') on either side of the assumed match, so the above tag results in

```
***@I'***ll fight you;
```

I can't figure it out.

(And if anyone has any additional tips and tricks on how to get it to match a tag like  '@username;;', where the end character is also a part of the name, lemme know. I figured that might be too complicated and better done programmatically.)

```
module PostsHelper

  def tag_users(content)
    # User tagging in format '@multiword name;'
    # Regexp /(\@)(.*?)(\;)/ for debugging; user configurable eventually
    start_character = '@'
    end_character = ';'
    tag_pattern = eval('/(#{start_character})(.*?)(#{end_character})/')
    name_pattern = eval('/(?<=#{start_character})(.*?)(?=#{end_character})/')

    # Iterate through all tags and replace with link
    content.gsub(tag_pattern) do
      tag = Regexp.last_match(0)
      tagged_name = tag[name_pattern, 1]
      tagged_user = User.where('lower(name) = ?', tagged_name.downcase).first
      if tagged_user
         "<a href='#{user_path(tagged_user.id)}'>@#{tagged_name}</a>"
      else
        '***' + tag + '***'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Edit: I called a quotation mark a comma. I hate myself.

Comment: I bet the quote in the data is being interpreted literally as the end of the tag string by one of your function calls.  Narrow it down by displaying the value of the variables tag_pattern, name_pattern, tag, tagged_name to find out who is causing the issue.  I suspect you will need to scan the tag string and escape or remove the quote before doing the replace operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
/(?<=@).[^;]*/
```

it should match everything in between the @ and the ; -- as tried now at http://www.rubular.com/.

I'd also caution against using the termination character within the username -- it will be difficult to differentiate @user;; from maybe mentioning @user; in a sentence that is followed by a semi-colon.

Comment: Nope, still hung up on quotations. I've been testing my expressions before implementation with RegExr, where they work perfectly fine, even with quotations.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your original code into my system -- only removing the reference to the User model -- and it works, with and without apostrophes.  Is there processing happening to the text before tag_users is called?  (Edit:  I also called them commas.  dammit.)